# RavenDB in docker container restart loses connection on Linux VM

Tags: azure, docker, virtual-machine, ravendb

I recently stood up a Linux VM on Azure and installed docker on it.
After, pulling down the latest docker image of RavenDB 4.0, as per the documentation I ran: docker run -p 8080:8080 ravendb/ravendb

I opened port 8080 on my VM and am able to hit the ip:8080 and reach the start up page of the RavenDB Portal. After walking through the steps, it asks me to hit restart. Once I click the button, I lose connection and the page return the dreaded "This site can’t be reached" page.

Is there a way to get to the Raven portal after it has restarted?

Looking at my docker containers on the VM, I notice that it creates a new container but both are exited. I tried starting each one independently and docker run but then I wind up at the beginning with the start of the RavenDB wizard in the portal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After walking through the steps, it asks me to hit restart. Once I
>   click the button, I lose connection and the page return the dreaded
>   "This site can’t be reached" page.

That means you have not configure it correctly.

Here is my steps, just for test, it works fine:

1. Follow the setup wizard, Select UNSECURE:
2. Enter the port and ip address like this:

[image]

3. Restart server.

At this time, you should check your Linux VM, output like this:
[image]

Then refresh your browser, you can load RavenDB studio:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah perfect! I was inputting the IP of my VM, not the 172.17.0.2 number. That worked thanks!